# How to pass the address of array[2] as a reference to a function in python

Tags: python, arrays, c, pass-by-reference

im trying to pass the address of an array `reg_value[2]` to a function in python

```
import array
reg_value = array.array('I',[0]*100)

def postdata(data):
        for i in range(2):
            print(data[i])

reg_value[0]=1
reg_value[1]=2
reg_value[2]=3
reg_value[3]=4

postdata(reg_value)
```

the above code prints the value 1 2

but i need to pass the address of `reg_value[2]` to print the value 3 4

i can achieve this in C programming like passing the address as `&reg_value[2]`

how to replicate the same in python?

Comment: C & Python are quite different for this. The easiest way to print 34 in your case is print ```reg_value[2]``` and ```reg_value[3]``` like you did for the indexes 0 & 1

Comment: Thanks, but this is just an example program. in real i need to send hundreds of values in an array to function for processing data. where the array index will vary in runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing subset reference of array/list as an argument in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509557/passing-subset-reference-of-array-list-as-an-argument-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass the address of anything in Python, but you can pass a slice which contains a subsequence.

```py
postdata(reg_value[2:])
```

This does create a copy of the items from the sequence.  Probably a better design is to allow the caller to specify a base index.

```py
def postdata(items, offset=0):
    for i in range(2):
        print(items[offset+i])
```

Comment: This is an `array.array` instance, not a list.

Comment: I don't see how that invalidates this answer. Or do you mean there is a better way to do it with this specific data type?

Comment: There does happen to be a better way to do it for `array.array` instances (take a memoryview and slice that, to avoid the copy), but I was mostly just pointing out it's an array because you kept saying "list".

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other method to avoid sending offset as an argument to the function?

Comment: I'm sure there are other ways, but maybe post a new question with more details about why this is unacceptable and what sort of solution you would like instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(2,4):
    print(data[i])
```

Comment: An explanation of how this solves the problem would greatly improve this answer. Also, this hardcoded `range(2,4)` will not handle OP's case where "*where the array index will vary in runtime.*"